# Why is it okay to call free with null pointer?

Tags: c, memory, standards, free

It's clear from the C standards that `NULL` is an acceptable input to `free()`, with the result being no operation performed.  However, this seems to violate the idea that `free()` must only be called on memory that was explicitly allocated using `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()`.

What's the reasoning behind this exception?  The only reason I can figure is so that callers do not have to explicitly check for `NULL` before calling `free()`.

Comment: `NULL` is a valid return value from `malloc` and friends. So any construct `free(malloc(...))` will be valid.

Comment: It is difficult to answer questions about reasoning for programming languages. What would be the advantage of *not* allowing `free(NULL)` and what error would you expect in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `malloc` function (as well as `calloc` and `realloc`) may return a NULL pointer if the requested size is 0.  Therefore, it makes sense that NULL pointer can also be passed to `free` since it was returned from a successful call to `malloc`:

Section 7.22.3p1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) specifies this behavior:

> If the space cannot be allocated, a null pointer is returned. If the
> size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is
> implementation-defined: either a null pointer is  returned,  or  the
> behavior  is  as  if  the  size  were  some  nonzero  value,  except
> that  the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.